# How to stop Docker Desktop without system tray icon (Windows)

Tags: docker-desktop

Docker Desktop is running, but it is not showing up in the system tray (a bug I assume?).  How can I shut it down?  I see no way to do this via the UX.  The only way I've seen to shut it down is via right-clicking the system try icon, but that's not showing up.  I could play whack-a-service in Task Manager, but I'm hoping there's a better way.

Overall, I'm not at all impressed with the UX of Docker Desktop.  The "modal as a full app element" decision is confusing at best (it took me a while to notice that "X" in the upper right), and the inability to do things like actually shut the service down is frustrating.